# How do I set up an ASP.NET MVC route in which the controller name is derived from multiple segments of the URL?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm building a website which needs to map the following URLs to their respective controllers;

- van-insurance/quote1 maps to EditVehicleController
- van-insurance/quote2 maps to EditProposerController
- van-insurance/quote3 maps to EditAdditionalDriversController
- van-insurance/quote4 maps to EditPolicyController

In each case the required action is Show, with no parameters.

I can add a route with the pattern "van-insurance/{quotePage}" which will match the four URLs, but I don't know how to get the value of "quotePage" and then use that to tell ASP .NET MVC which controller to use.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got this to work thanks to Mystere Man and Nikolay Kostov, thanks guys for your help. I created a custom route which has a dictionary to map between page name and controller, like so;

```
private static readonly IDictionary<string, Type> Map = CreateControllerPageMap();

private static IDictionary<string, Type> CreateControllerPageMap()
{
    var map = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
    map.Add("quote1", typeof(EditVehicleController));
    map.Add("quote2", typeof(EditProposerController));
    map.Add("quote3", typeof(EditAdditionalDriversController));
    map.Add("quote4", typeof(EditPolicyController));
    return map;
}
```

My override for GetRouteData looks like this;

```
public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    var routeData = base.GetRouteData(httpContext);
    SetRouteData(routeData);
    return routeData;
}

private static void SetRouteData(RouteData routeData)
{
    var quotePage = routeData.GetRequiredString("quotePage");
    var controller = Map[quotePage].Name.Replace("Controller", string.Empty);
    routeData.Values["controller"] = controller;
    routeData.Values["action"] = "Edit";
}
```

The final step was just to register the route like this;

```
routes.Add("QuoteJourney", new QuoteJourneyRoute("compare-van-insurance/{quotePage}", new MvcRouteHandler()));
```

That worked fine. However I then found that URLs generated by RedirectToAction were incorrect, because ASP .NET MVC did not know how to map back from controller name and action name to a URL. This was resolved by overriding GetVirtualPath;

```
public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
{
    var virtualPathData = base.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, values);
    SetVirtualPath(values, virtualPathData);
    return virtualPathData;
}

private static void SetVirtualPath(IDictionary<string, object> values, VirtualPathData virtualPathData)
{
    var controller = values["controller"] + "Controller";
    var quotePage = Map.Keys.Single(k => Map[k] == Map.Values.Single(v => v.Name == controller));
    virtualPathData.VirtualPath = "compare-van-insurance/" + quotePage;
}
```

Sorted!

Comment: Glad you got it working.  This is the sort of thing I like, giving someone enough information for them to figure it out on their own.  This way you more fully understand what its doing and can better maintain and modify it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "van-insurance/quote1",
    url: "van-insurance/quote1",
    defaults: new { controller = "EditVehicleController", action = "Show", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "van-insurance/quote2",
    url: "van-insurance/quote2",
    defaults: new { controller = "EditProposerController", action = "Show", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "van-insurance/quote3",
    url: "van-insurance/quote3",
    defaults: new { controller = "EditAdditionalDriversController", action = "Show", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "van-insurance/quote4",
    url: "van-insurance/quote4",
    defaults: new { controller = "EditPolicyController", action = "Show", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Anyway I advice you to use another approach since this one is not easily changeable.

```
var vanInsuranceRoutes = new List<Tuple<string, string>>
                    {
                        new Tuple<string, string>("quote1", "EditVehicleController"),
                        new Tuple<string, string>("quote2", "EditProposerController"),
                        new Tuple<string, string>("quote3", "EditAdditionalDriversController"),
                        new Tuple<string, string>("quote4", "EditPolicyController"),
                    };

foreach (var route in vanInsuranceRoutes)
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: string.Format("van-insurance/{0}", route.Item1),
        url: string.Format("van-insurance/{0}", route.Item1),
        defaults: new { controller = route.Item2, action = "Show", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
}
```

You can improve the quality of the code, but you got the idea.

Comment: That is actually what we've got at the moment, but we want to find a better way so we can avoid all the repetition.

Comment: Whilst your edited answer works, it still requires the creation of four routes. The answer I want is one that shows how to create one route for the four URLs.

Comment: Somewhere your code should map numbers 1,2,3,4 to controller names. I don't think you can do this with only one route. If you insist on creating only one route you can research for custom controller factory.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in your route to indicate how to map to the controller, as such, you have to have code somewhere that does this mapping.

If you are only interested in a single route that calls code to do the mapping, then you might consider something like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16511451/61164

Essentially, you can build your controller based on a single route, but in the Custom Route Controller, you can map your route values to the proper controller.

Comment: Thanks that looks useful, will try it and post an answer if I'm successful.